# What does the Einstein-Hilbert action look like in terms of Riemannian metric of positive signature?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

For a 4-manifold to admit a Lorentzian metric is equivalent to that manifold having vanishing Euler characteristic. Any spacetime that admits a Lorentzian metric $g^{\mathcal{L}}$ can have that metric written in terms of a Riemannian metric $g^{\mathcal{R}}$ [(for example Gibbons and Hawking)](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/gibhaw2.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjp6qLaqM_8AhXyrIkEHUWKDCQQFnoECAcQAg&usg=AOvVaw2IQXNOhLDdr3jLfhgVhLRd):

$$g_{ab}^{\mathcal{L}}=g_{ab}^{\mathcal{R}}-2\frac{v_{a}v_{b}}{g_{cd}^{\mathcal{R}}v^{c}v^{d}}$$

Where $v$ is a global nonvanishing vector field. Let's suppose we know $v$. What does the Einstein-Hilbert action look like in this form (ie in terms of the Riemannian metric and line field $v$)?

I imagine there are papers on this somewhere so I'm not rebuilding the wheel? I'd prefer an approach based on tetrads or solder forms, but I'll take what I can get.
NOTE: I am assuming time orientability